# Angular2 - Can I tell what module a component is a member of at runtime?

Tags: angular

I am having a hard time upgrading to RC6.  I have multiple modules and I get runtime errors saying a component is not part of the module.  I tried putting everything in app.module but that didn't solve it.

Is there a way to tell (at runtime) which module a component is part of?  I just need this from troubleshooting.

Here is my error:

> Can't bind to 'fullList' since it isn't a known property of
>   'autocomplete-component'.
>   1. If 'autocomplete-component' is an Angular component and it has 'fullList' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

It look like autocomplete-component is defined as it should be.  It was a declaration in app.module.  Now i moved it to a shared module and imported it in all my modules.  I still get the error.

I need a way to verify, at runtime, that autocomplete-component is indeed in te module.  Plus, I need ot make sure that the component using it is in the module I think it is.  It's loaded by a route.

Comment: You may check if a particular module contains Component, not sure if you may do other way around.

Comment: How do I check this at runtime?

Comment: Added answer on checking if a component is present in a Module at runtime, the Module must export the component you are checking.

Comment: can you add your code here?

Answer (score 2):

Each component of a module has to be declared in the Declarations[] part of ngModule.  Once that is done, the module can find its components and the angular pre-scan can find the components.

Comment: I understand that.  By looking at the code everything seems to be setup properly.  But how do I know at runtime what module a component is part of.  At design time I know what it should be and it looks correct.

Comment: I declared the 'missing' component in a shared module and all my module import it.  I still get the error.

Comment: did you export it from the shared module?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below,

```
import { Compiler} from '@angular/core';
constructor(private _compiler: Compiler) {}

checkComponentInModule(selector){

// loop over all your imported Module
this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(<module>).then(_module => {
            let _componentFactories = _module.componentFactories.filter(_c => {
                return _c.selector == selector;
            });

            if (!!_componentFactories && _componentFactories.length > 0) {
                // Yay Component exists in this module!!
            }
        });
}
```

Module must export the component you are checking.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I think I can't do what I want. I am getting template parse errors so the code never runs. But those parse errors are what I need to troubleshoot. I updated the post with the error. –

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hold control and click on the Component Class's declaration. You will get all it's references.
[image]

Locate the module.ts class .